# Mongoose keeps giving both _id and id with same value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some Mongoose schemas, whose certain fields need getter and setters.

For that, i've set the following:

```
MySchema.set('toObject',{getters:true});
MySchema.set('toJSON',{getters:true});
```

Whenever I send/read the result of `MySchema.find()`, it gives me both `_id` and `id` fields, which have same value.
I think thats a virtual field (correct me if i'm wrong here)

How do i stop this? I don't want to process through each and every object and remove the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Documented here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id):

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an `id` virtual getter by default which returns the documents `_id` field cast to a string, or in the case of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an `id` getter added to your schema, you may disable it passing this option at schema construction time.

Just set the `id` field to `false` while creating the schema:

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { id: false });
```